# Electrostatics homework: Electric field of a wired conductor

Tags: physics

I need help with the following problem:

Wire conductor of length ***l*** consists of two part with equal length in series, and of specific conductivity ***σ1*** and ***σ2***. When conductor is connected to constant voltage ***U***, what are electric fields in parts of this conductor?

$$E_1=\frac{2σ_2U}{l(σ_1+σ_2)}$$ $$E_2=\frac{2σ_1U}{l(σ_1+σ_2)}$$

I don't know how to derive these equations. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: I think you missed the assumption that both conductors have the same cross-sectional area.

Comment: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity)

Comment: Have you considered actually *going to class*?

Answer (score -1):

**HINT:**

1. \$R=\dfrac{l}{\sigma A}\$
2. \$I=\dfrac{U}{R_1+R_2}\$
3. \$J=\dfrac{I}{A}\$
4. \$E=\dfrac{J}{\sigma}\$

Where R=resistance of conductor, I=current through conductor, A=cross-sectional area of conductor, J=current density in conductor, E=electric field in conductor.

**ANSWER:**

> Since both conductor are in series; \$R=R_1+R_2\$ 
>  -------------------------------------------------------------
>  \$I=\frac{U}{R_1+R_2}=\dfrac{U}{\dfrac{l_1}{\sigma_1 A_1}+\dfrac{l_2}{\sigma_2 A_2}}=\dfrac{2U}{l\left(\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1 A_1}+\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2 A_2}\right)}\; \because \;l_1=l_2=\frac{l}{2} \$
> -------------------------------------------------------------
>  \$E_1=\dfrac{J_1}{\sigma_1}=\dfrac{I}{\sigma_1 A_1}=\dfrac{2U}{l\left(1+\dfrac{\sigma_1 A_1}{\sigma_2 A_2}\right)}=\dfrac{2U\sigma_2}{l\left(\sigma_2+\sigma_1\right)}\$ if \$A_1=A_2\$
> -------------------------------------------------------------
>  Conversely,  \$E_2=\dfrac{2U\sigma_1}{l\left(\sigma_2+\sigma_1\right)}\$ if \$A_1=A_2\$

Comment: We try not to answer HW problems here.